# Populate a MySQL table from a CSV file that has many more columns

Tags: mysql, csv

Everywhere I looks, I find a solution to how to populate a DB table if the table has more columns than the CSV file, but what if it is the other way around and I don't want to type all the columns to the query.

Is there any smart way of doing it?

Right now, all I can come up with is this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3, ...)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Which would just skip the `@dummy` fields of the file.

Comment: It seems correct approach as per MySQL docs. What's the issue?

Comment: I was hoping for a smarter way of doing it to avoid having to type `@dummy` 42 times and searching for positions of the columns that I am actually going to use.

Comment: LOAD DATA on all columns, then ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN... after the fact on the columns you don't want?